# Count unique elements in data frame row and return one with maximum occurrence

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

Is it possible to count unique elements in data frame row and return one with maximum occurrence and as result form the vector.

```
example:
a a a b b b b -> b 
c v f w w r t -> w
s s d f b b b -> b
```

Comment: @flodel, while I agree that the underlying concept is the same in both questions, if one were searching for this specific question, I'm not sure if the other would come up, or if the connection would even be obvious to everyone.  I think there is value in leaving this question open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `apply` to use `table` function on every row of dataframe.

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("a a a b b b b\nc v f w w r t\ns s d f b b b"), header = F)

df$result <- apply(df, 1, function(x) names(table(x))[which.max(table(x))])

df
##   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 result
## 1  a  a  a  b  b  b  b      b
## 2  c  v  f  w  w  r  t      w
## 3  s  s  d  f  b  b  b      b
```

Comment: @Marat, geektrader, how about ties?

Comment: In the event of ties, the **FIRST** max element will be chosen by `which.max`

Answer (score 1):

Yes with `table`

```
x=c("a", "a", "a", "b" ,"b" ,"b" ,"b")
table(x)
x
a b 
3 4
```

EDIT with data.table

```
DT = data.table(x=sample(letters[1:5],10,T),y=sample(letters[1:5],10,T))
#DT
#    x y
# 1: d a
# 2: c d
# 3: d c
# 4: c a
# 5: a e
# 6: d c
# 7: c b
# 8: a b
# 9: b c
#10: c d

f = function(x) names(table(x))[which.max(table(x))]
DT[,lapply(.SD,f)]
#   x y
#1: c c
```

Comment: it works for vector, but doesn't work for data frame row, and command should return only element with maximum occurrence

Comment: ohhh... fair enough data.table solution on the way

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you want to keep **ALL** max's, you need to ask for them explicitly.

You can save them as a list inside the data.frame.  If there is only one per row, then the list will be simplified to a common vector

```
  df$result <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {T <- table(x); list(T[which(T==max(T))])})
```

#### With Ties for max:

```
df2 <- df[, 1:6]
df2$result <- apply(df2, 1, function(x) {T <- table(x); list(T[which(T==max(T))])})

> df2
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 result
1  a  a  a  b  b  b   3, 3
2  c  v  f  w  w  r      2
3  s  s  d  f  b  b   2, 2
```

#### With No Ties for max:

```
df$result <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {T <- table(x); list(T[which(T==max(T))])})

> df
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 result
1  a  a  a  b  b  b  b      4
2  c  v  f  w  w  r  t      2
3  s  s  d  f  b  b  b      3
```